# using lua_call/lua_pcall without popping the stack

Tags: lua, lua-api

When I use `lua_call` or `lua_pcall`, in addition to running the lua chunk, it also pops the chunk from the stack. Is there any way I can run the chunk while still keeping the chunk on the stack?

Comment: You can make additional copy of chunk with `lua_pushvalue` or `lua_copy`

Comment: instead of making a copy, can I just not ever remove it from the stack?

Comment: I guess you cannot.  This is how `lua_call` works.

Comment: is there any reason why, it seems odd to bake in this extra step? Sorry if I'm missing something obvious/fundimental, I'm new to the lua-api so it's possible I'm being a dumb noob.

Comment: Probably, this behavior of `lua_call` was chosen by Lua authors to facilitate calculation of chained functions such as `local x = f(g())`, otherwise you would have to manually move all values returned by `g()` in the Lua API stack.